# StmpClient use works for remote users via VPN but not for users in office, on the network

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, smtpclient

I've implemented the .NET SmtpClient to send emails programmatically.  Multiple users of the application and at various stages, an email is automatically sent.  For users that are running the application from home, over VPN, the email almost always works.  For users at the office, the email fails, "Failure sending mail" is exception message with no inner exception.  The email server is MS Exchange, for large financial institution.  Not using SSL, using port 25.

```
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient (getSmtpServer(), getSmtpPort());
            mailClient.Timeout = 20000;
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            MailAddress from = new MailAddress ( getSmtpFromAcct(),
                                                 "My Application",
                                                 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress ( toEmail );

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

            for( int i = 1; i < toUsers.Count; i++)
            {
               BeanUser  beanUser = toUsers[ i ];
               message.To.Add( beanUser.getEmail() );
            }

            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = messageBody;

            mailClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: This is a Windows application, and set for Target Framework of 3.5.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.